# three.js - how to generate stars efficiently

Tags: three.js

I'm new to three.js trying to implement night sky, for stars I'm generating 500 spheres of 6x6 segments each with random color and random spherical coordinates after generation I'm animating rotation of the full scene.

Sometimes this freezes so I suppose my approach is inefficient - how do I generate stars programmatically in efficient way? As far as I understand easier solution could be extra texture on the inner side of big outer sphere(s) but in this case I will need to get extra assets plus this could be quite flat

```js
function randomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  35,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: false
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let spheres = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
  let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.02 * randomArbitrary(0.5, 1), 6, 6);
  let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color(1, randomArbitrary(190, 220) / 255, Math.round(Math.random()))
  });

  let sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(sphere);
  spheres.push(sphere);
  sphere.position.setFromSpherical(new THREE.Spherical(5 + 5 * Math.random(), 2 * Math.PI * Math.random(), 2 * Math.PI * Math.random()))
}
scene.rotation.x = 0.2;
scene.rotation.z = 0.6;
camera.position.z = 5;
var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(3);
scene.add(axesHelper);

var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  scene.rotation.y += 0.001;
  scene.rotation.z -= 0.001;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try to use `THREE.Points()` with `THREE.BufferGeometry()` + `THREE.ShaderMaterial()`. For example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=points#webgl_custom_attributes_points

Comment: @prisoner849 woow this looks impressive, will give it a try!

Comment: http://stars.chromeexperiments.com/

Comment: @StrangerintheQ It's pretty clear "enthusiasts at Google" can make this, but how this suppose to help me?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry you can open debugger and saw how it works